# Best way to handle complex State in React

Tags: reactjs, state

I am attempting to create a react application which takes the following data structure to render the application...

```
 var cellTest = [
    {
      type: 'group',
      children: [
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Dex', abbreviation: 'DEX', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Constitution', abbreviation: 'CON', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Intelligence', abbreviation: 'INT', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Wisdom', abbreviation: 'WIS', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Charisma', abbreviation: 'CHA', value: 10},
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'group',
      children: [
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Dex', abbreviation: 'DEX', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Dex', abbreviation: 'DEX', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', height: 2, width: 2, name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', height: 2, width: 2, name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', height: 2, width: 2, name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', height: 2, width: 3, name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Dex', abbreviation: 'DEX', value: 10},
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'group',
      children: [
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Dex', abbreviation: 'DEX', value: 10},
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'group',
      children: [
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Dex', abbreviation: 'DEX', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
        {type: 'Cell', name: 'Dex', abbreviation: 'DEX', value: 10},
      ]
    }, 
  ]
```

Currently, this object is passed to a 'Sheet' component which iterates through the array and renders a 'Group' component passing all data down as props.  The group component then iterates through the children array and renders a Cell component with the corresponding props. Eventually each cell will store values that must be bound to this data structure.  I got this working fine with dummy data being passed down, however, when I decided to try to hook up state ( which I have little experience with ) everything blew up in my face.

If I click on a Cell component and change a value I hoped to send a message to the parent component which would house the 'Sheet' in State.  That message would alter the state which would trigger a re-rendering ( I *think) of the component which cascade the changes down.  However, when I did this I got some weird errors and upon googling it seems that react cannot handle state with nested data?

What is the best way to approach state management in this situation? Should I flatten my data somehow?

I apologize if this question is a bit vague, however, I'm newish to react and having my mind blown :)

UPDATE:

I attempted to, as a test, simply add a new group to the state but it breaks.

```
 let newGroup =     {
    type: 'group',
    children: [
      {type: 'Cell', name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
      {type: 'Cell', name: 'Strength', abbreviation: 'STR', value: 10},
      {type: 'Cell', name: 'Dex', abbreviation: 'DEX', value: 10},
      {type: 'Cell', name: 'Constitution', abbreviation: 'CON', value: 10},
      {type: 'Cell', name: 'Intelligence', abbreviation: 'INT', value: 10},
      {type: 'Cell', name: 'Wisdom', abbreviation: 'WIS', value: 10},
      {type: 'Cell', name: 'Charisma', abbreviation: 'CHA', value: 10},
    ]
  }

  const [sheet, setSheet] = useState(cellTest);

  function addGroup(){
    setSheet(prevSheet => prevSheet.push(newGroup))
  }
```

This produces the following errors

```
TypeError: props.sheet.map is not a function

   8 | console.log('BOOM', props.sheet)
>  9 | let sheet = props.sheet.map((group, index)=>{
     | ^  10 |     // Render each group and pass data within the group as props to that group
  11 |     return <Group key={'Group'+index} {...props.sheet[index]}/>
  12 | })
```

And in my console, I can see that the value of my props.sheet ( as read by the component which my state is passed down to ) is now the integer 5 for some reason.  I even logged the value of the sheet being passed down before it hit the component and it was okay until the component tried to read it.  The only thing that I can think of is that react does not know how to update my components because of the nested state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign an ID to each cell.

Then write a method in your parent element that can take a cell ID & value, and then create a new state object by copying all the unchanged data and merging it with new objects containing the new value for the given cell.

Pass that method through as a callback to each cell, and call that to update the state upon change.

*You can use a library like [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) to aid with the deep-copying.*

EDIT:
Regarding your update, you're on the right lines, but the [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method adds elements to the end of the array and **returns the new length of the array.** Also you can't just add to an existing object, you need to create a new object, or React will not spot the change and will not re-render.

Try:

```
addGroup = () => setSheet(prevSheet => [...prevSheet, newGroup]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried something similar and kept getting an error. I even simplified it for testing and just passed a callback that added a new group to the state object and attempted to save it.  Upon saving the new state object it broke - suddenly when it tried to .map my array had been replaced by an integer.  It is possible this was a different bug so I will update my findings here after another attempt.

thanks again!

Comment: Regarding the library, I appreciate it and will look into it, however, I've already been told to look into context and redux.  My thinking is that since I'm new to react I would like to maximize my use of base react so that I understand why I'm incorporating new libraries and can explain that to the employer I hope to have someday :D :D :(

Comment: Your update worked! Thank you for the clarification, that actually makes a lot of sense.